# Why the full image path is not stored in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I use Linq-to-SQL for storing and retrieving images from a SQL Server database. I use a `varchar(max)` datatype for it.

Here is my code for saving the image,

```
 EventBL r = new EventBL();
 r.Banner_SignUp_Page = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fuBanner.FileName);
 r.Insert();
```

and here is for retrieving it.

```
var result1 = from a in db.EMR_INVITATIONs
              join b in db.EMR_EVENTs on a.EventID equals b.EventID
              where b.EventID == (int)Session["eventid"]
              select new
              {
                 Banner = b.Banner_SignUp_Page,
              };

var ev = result1.First();

Image1.ImageUrl = ev.Banner;
```

but in the database I found that whole path of image isn't stored.

In database some of the path is stored, and I can't retrieve image from database.

If there is solution or improvement in my code?

Please let me know,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you debug through your code, does `r.Banner_Signup_Page` really contain the **full path** before your store it?

Comment: What is the value of r.Banner_SignUp_Page right before you store it in the database?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Share" is r.Banner_Signup_Page.  Not full path is coming this is half path.

Comment: Try to `debug` it `locally` you will find your answer .. And just a take look into  `r.Insert()` procedure may be in `sql parameter` you did not use `varchar(max)` ..

Comment: Can you show example of path that you try to store and the actually stored value that you retreive from the DB?

Comment: In r.Insert(),  right path is coming but in database only half of path is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your path   inside a  DirectoryInfo object:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft 
Share\img.png");
```

Then use:

```
directory.FullName;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you leave it upto user/client, you can't really do it perfectly because you can never know the ength of image, user is going to upload.
You can do it hard coded to save trouble/exception etc, like:

```
string imagePath ="~/Project/Images/Banners/"+Image_Name+".jpg";
```

where Image_Name is a string created by your logic like:

```
string Image_Name = "userid_" + userid + "_avatar";
```